# how to do a two level sort of columns in a recordset or array using vb6

Tags: sorting, vb6

I want to know how to do a 2 level sort of columns in a recordset or array using vb6 just SQL order by two or more columns. Right now I'm able to sort based on only one column. Please help me. I'm sorting the recordset that is displayed in a datagrid and using TDBGrid_Headclick event to sort the whole data grid.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try `rs.Sort = "Name, Code, Total DESC"`

Comment: Thank you your help wqw. It works when clicked on a column for the first time but when i again click the same column it is not sorting in ASC order. Please help me.

Comment: You have to construct the `Sort` property from sorted columns including direction. You cannot simply append `rs.Sort = rs.Sort & "," MyColumn.DataField`, there is some (basic) logic you have to implement. Post another Q with sample code, incl. what have you tried and what does not work.

Comment: Thank you so much wqw. It works. Could you please answer my two more questions of vb6. Thank you once again.